# I have a string date format 01/01/2017 6:54 PM and want to convert it to 2017-01-01T00:00:05.383+0100 ISOFormat in scala

Tags: scala, jodatime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

```
   def cleantz( time : String ) : String = {
    var sign_builder= new StringBuilder ++= time
    println(sign_builder)
    var clean_sign = ""
    if (sign_builder.charAt(23).toString == "-"){
      clean_sign= sign_builder.replace(23,24,"-").toString()
    }else{
      clean_sign = sign_builder.replace(23,24,"+").toString()
    }
    var time_builder= new StringBuilder ++= clean_sign
    if (time_builder.charAt(26).toString == ":"){
      val cleanz = time_builder.deleteCharAt(26)
      cleanz.toString()
    }else{
      time_builder.toString()
    }
  }

    val start = ISO8601Format.parse(cleantz(01/01/2017 6:54 PM))
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 23

Comment: why am I getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: What do you suppose happens when you call `charAt(23)` on a `StringBuilder` that is less than 23 characters in length?

Comment: i have edited the code, that is what i actually ran

Comment: You're trying to get the character at position 23 when the string has less than 24 characters (because the first character is at position zero, the second is at position 1 and so on). So you should check the `length()` first. But anyway, if the string you have is in the format `01/01/2017 6:54 PM`, why do you need to check if the string contains `-`? You need to parse this to a date and then format with `ISO8601Format`

Comment: You tagged your question jodatime, and while Joda-Time is a good option, it also in maintenance mode, and its authors recommend we move on to `java.time`, which is developed by the same people drawing on all the experience from Joda-Time. So wouldn’t that be a still better option for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

For the sake of completeness I should like to contribute the modern answer. It’s quite simple and straightforward.

I am sorry that I can neither write Scala code nor test it on my computer. I have to trust you to translate from Java.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);

public static String cleantz(String time) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(time, inputFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1))
            .toString();
}
```

Now `cleantz("01/01/2017 6:54 PM")` returns `2017-01-01T18:54+01:00`, which is in ISO 8601 format. I would immediately suppose that you’re set. If for some reason you want or need the seconds too, replace `.toString();` with:

```
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

Now the result is `2017-01-01T18:54:00+01:00`. In both cases the milliseconds would have been printed if there were any.

Since `AM` and `PM` are hardly used in other languages than English, I suggest you give an English-speaking locale to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` (in my example I used `Locale.US`). Failing to provide a locale will cause the code to fail on many computers with non-English language settings.

### Why `java.time`?

- `SimpleDateFormat` and friends are long outdated and notoriously troublesome. I cannot count the questions asked on Stack Overflow because `SimpleDateFormat` behaved differently from what every sane programmer would have expected, or offered no help to debug the simple errors we all make from time to time.
- Joda-Time was good for a long time. Today the [Joda-Time homepage](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says:

  > Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
  >   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
  >   to `java.time` (JSR-310).
- `java.time` is the modern Java date & time API built using the experience from Joda-Time and under the same lead developer, Stephen Colebourne. It is built into Java 8 and later, and a backport exists for Java 6 and 7, so you can use the same classes there too.

Comment: This is a great feedback. I am knew to programming and scala in particular, so your answer has helped me understand why I should use each method and when to look for alternative.

Comment: Good Answer. Also consider calling [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) rather than hard-coding a specific formatting pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input string is `01/01/2017 6:54 PM`: it has 18 characters. When you call `charAt(23)`, it tries to get the character at position 23, which doesn't exist: the string has positions from zero (the first `0`) to 17 (the `M`). If you try to get a position greater than that, it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

But you don't need to do all this string manipulation. If you have a string that represents a date in some format, and want to convert it to another format, all you need is:

1. parse the original string to a date
2. format this date to another format

So you need 2 different Joda formatter's (one for each step). But there's one additional detail.

The input has a date (`01/01/2017`) and a time (`6:54 PM`), and the output has a date (`2017-01-01`), a time (`18:54:00.000`) and the [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (`+0100`). So you'll have an additional step:

1. parse the original string to a date
2. add the `+0100` offset to the parsed date
3. format this date to another format

With Joda-Time, this can be achieved with the following code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat

val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
// parse the date
val localDate = LocalDateTime.parse("01/01/2017 6:54 PM", fmt)
// add the +01:00 offset
val dt = localDate.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(1))
// format to ISO8601
print(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(dt))
```

The output will be:

> 2017-01-01T18:54:00.000+01:00

Note that the offset is printed as `+01:00`. If you want exactly `+0100` (without the `:`), you'll need to create another formatter:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
println(formatter.print(dt))
```

The output will be:

> 2017-01-01T18:54:00.000+0100

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to achieve the same result. The error occurred because I was trying to parse the wrong date format.

```
   val inputForm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a")
   val outputForm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")

   val dateFormat1 = start_iso
   val dateFormat2 = stop_iso

   val start = outputForm.format(inputForm.parse(start_iso))
 val stop = outputForm.format(inputForm.parse(stop_iso))

   println(start)
println(stop)
```

Comment: Yeah, but why use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`? The modern `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` is generally much nicer and more helpful.